# Is there a hapi-swagger library that supports OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi, hapi, hapi-swagger

We are using [hapi-swagger](https://github.com/hapi-swagger/hapi-swagger) for our hapi Node APIs to generate our Swagger pages.

We are also trying to use [Postman Contract Test Generator](https://github.com/allenheltondev/postman-contract-test-generator) to create automated tests for our APIs.  This works great for our non-node APIs.

However, Postman Contract Test Generator requires OpenAPI 3.0, and as of the most recent release of hapi-swagger it is still using the Swagger 2.0 spec.

Is anyone aware of a library that leverages OpenAPI 3.0 instead?

Answer (score 0):

The team left a message that they only support swagger 2.0, but did leave a recommendation on a way to possibly solve our need.

https://github.com/hapi-swagger/hapi-swagger/issues/760